# Testing and Incorporating Random Effects in Survival Regression

Tags: mixed-model, survival, repeated-measures

Below I have an example data set in which I'm modeling the time-to-event given two fixed-effect factors `a` and `b`, and a random-effect `id` representing a specific system. In the data, `y` is my response and it can be censored, `complete == 0`. Since there is censoring I'm using survival modeling specifically `survival::survreg`. I simulated the data assuming a normal response but just for simplicity.

I want to know if system-to-system variability is significant hence I specifically included it as a term in `mod`. (Side note: I believe I need a parametric model because ultimately I want to find $Pr(time<X | a, b)$. My plan would be to design an experiment and specifically test if system-to-system variability is significant because in general I don't know another way to simply estimate the system-to-system variability within the model and then specifically test if it is above something I would care about. Even if I did know how to test that hypothesis, I'm not sure how I would do that in a setting where I have censoring, since these models don't appear to support random effects/frailty.)

I don't actually care about predicting time-to-event for these particular systems because they're just a random selection from a larger population. So, after testing my hypothesis, I would like to specify a model that allows me to predict time-to-event for any random system, and add the variability due to `id` back into the estimate for the model scale parameter. At first I thought I could just remove `id` and the estimate for scale would adjust appropriately, but then I realized I was probably not accounting for dependence between observations, and so would be biasing the scale estimate to be too low (this is my `mod2`). Then I realized `survreg` has a `cluster` argument and based on my interpretation of that I could add `id` there to account for dependence between observations. But, there doesn't appear to be any difference between `mod2` and `mod3`. So, I'm not sure I'm appropriately estimating variance that includes system-to-system variance, and accounting for dependence between observations.

Ultimately, I want to know if system-to-system variability is significant (above some value). Is there a better way to approach that? And, I want to create a model that allows me to predict $Pr(time<X  | a, b)$ for any given system, so variability would need to include system-to-system variability and account for dependence. Is `mod3` already doing that, and if not how would I go about doing this?

```r
df <- structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(3.26929742382298, 
    4.53114357864273, 4.60748705769383, 3.66367202748024, 3.60339975174583, 
    5.62915408515664, 3.64624718709751, 1.42962146166766, 1.30650049618921, 
    5.61594670417012, 3.56114991343261, 2.90426493230704, 5.33081428734092, 
    4.4468917639601, 3.80591195313923, 3.59352602872529, 6, 5.02854403654424, 
    1.63266901770139, 4.84643518333852, 4.64646233097725, 3.79696218021276, 
    1.52452686442184, 2.31343035760782, 5.12691234029955, 5.83801932729357, 
    3.34581840898551, 3.38150741733905, 3.98077477160601, 1.29589299723746, 
    2.43899048753085, 1.77004740191484, 4.53958023188868, 5.57858838493128, 
    4.77331394964177, 2.68176493257508, 3.53501745110821, 4.26050503442007, 
    3.75005476932345, 1.18192642948869, 4.55545382605327, 5.4635695047017, 
    5.76949594826958, 3.74817724327111, 6, 4.62781426082135, 
    2.8126158503946, 3.54233497740739, 2.80595535587881, 5.94953555255156, 
    6, 2.24916778530024, 2.49528039300557, 4.21606177364399, 
    2.85890042665913, 5.96390897323753, 4.5696903228557, 4.96315937063162, 
    3.67055356512646, 1.81364051363185, 4.19824842058448, 0.507622027976411, 
    5.1133922636573, 2.44493997863081, 6, 5.62996085484595, 3.55177691511373, 
    4.83278609173004, 3.32950899280437, 2.1502053399121, 4.16782479354695, 
    2.3657176304431, 4.50165802744744, 3.9115119862275, 2.61571858071789, 
    1.94699690077225, 3.85871440979462, 5.12861282734017, 0.776132131835725, 
    3.252401613923, 5.12797588377574, 5.52320008287, 3.17227444150401, 
    3.48357854182989, 4.31570815747131, 2.40127992482549, 4.72686168028773, 
    3.95566389485539, 6, 6, 5.45442619984441, 2.0018082488094, 
    3.87075731891542, 2.19373651792322, 3.02055448561179, 2.10010542443457, 
    4.56317380971635, 2.43361752717133, 3.73704315860611, 1.81812303412177, 
    6, 4.43654354650618, 4.42674367672321, 2.93776036921988, 
    6, 2.97494564603199, 2.93608323141461, 5.07697368476795, 
    2.93901544134742, 2.90398885591002, 2.32584807714999, 1.73507066849021, 
    5.19802660703162, 5.65797905839819, 4.35070083809204, 3.15776036832507, 
    6, 3.70878632745045, 3.46132064520567, 2.88036932845041), .Dim = c(120L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
    "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
    "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
    "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", 
    "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
    "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", 
    "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", 
    "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", 
    "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", 
    "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", 
    "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
    "116", "117", "118", "119", "120"), NULL)), complete = c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -120L
))

library(survival)
mod <- survreg(Surv(y, complete) ~ a + b + id, data = df, dist = "gaussian")
mod2 <- survreg(Surv(y, complete) ~ a + b, data = df, dist = "gaussian")
mod3 <- survreg(Surv(y, complete) ~ a + b, cluster = id, data = df, dist = "gaussian")

anova(mod)
# Analysis of Deviance Table
#
#  distribution with  link
#
# Response: Surv(y, cens)
#
# Scale estimated
#
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
#               Df Deviance Resid. Df  -2*LL Pr(>Chi)    
# NULL                            118 424.98             
# mode           1   3.5883       117 421.39 0.058188 .  
# concentration  1  19.6154       116 401.77 9.47e-06 ***
# id             5  18.8474       111 382.92 0.002052 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


mod$scale
# 1.248854

mod2$scale
# 1.350591

mod3$scale
# 1.350591
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cluster` argument in `survreg()` doesn't model random/frailty effects. It just adjusts the coefficient variance-covariance matrix to provide robust error estimates that take within-individual correlations into account. The point estimates are thus the same as without that argument, as you found. That's not what you evidently want.

The `survival` package can model gamma frailties in `coxph()` models, but not in `survreg()` models. As the [main survival vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf) says in Section 5.5.3:

> The penalty functions in `survreg` currently use the same code as those for `coxph`. This works well in the case of ridge and pspline, but frailty terms are more problematic in that the code to automatically choose the tuning parameter for the random effect no longer solves an MLE equation. The current code will not lead to the correct choice of penalty.

The [`coxme` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=coxme) handles Gaussian random effects in Cox models.

I'm not convinced that you need a parametric model to accomplish what you need, as it's possible to get survival estimates from Cox models and frailties are pretty simple to interpret in the context of proportional hazards. If you do need parametric modeling, the [survival task view](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Survival) suggests possibilities in R. The [`frailtypack` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=frailtypack) provides extensive tools for this type of modeling, and the [`MCMCglmm` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/index.html) builds corresponding Bayesian models.

With your `dist="gaussian"`, what you are trying to do also goes under the name of [tobit regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model). Try searching under that name, too. This [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-do-i-run-a-random-effect-tobit-model-using-nlmixed/) illustrates mixed tobit models in SAS.